# How to pass parameters between node.js and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am a new user of node.js and mongodb and still learning. Please excuse if the question seems very simple. My node.js MongoDB query script (`hello.js`) is-

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var assert = require('assert');
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/flood';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
        var collec_name="99"
        var field_name ="data1"
        var value=311

        db.collection(collec_name).find({data0:value}, {[field_name]:1, _id:0}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
      });
    });
```

The query runs fine with command- `node hello.js` and got the expected value `result` (for instance, output value of `result` is 0.000115). Note that `var collec_name="99"`, `var field_name ="data1"` and `var value=311` contain fixed values.

My HTML file (`index.html`) is-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var c_n = "99";
var f = "data1";
var v = 311;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0.000115;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to pass the values of variable `c_n`, `v` and `f` from `index.html` to `hello.js` by replacing three statements of `hello.js` as-

```
var collec_name=c_n
var field_name = f
var value = v
```

Then, I want to pass value of `result` from `hello.js` to the `index.html` by replacing one statement of `index.html` as-

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

So, how can I achieve these parameter passing so that if I run the `index.html` page, I can display the value of `result` on the web? Any solution script based on my scripts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Generally on Stack Overflow, if you find the answer to your own question, the usual approach is to add your own answer to the question and mark it as the correct one.  You should not edit the question itself to be the answer, as that will be confusing for future users (who will naturally expect the question to be a question!)

You might want to roll back your last few question edits and post a separate answer instead.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Certainly!  (That's an exemplary answer, by the way; thank you for including so much detail.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Comment: Happy to contribute to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

To send data between your back-end and your client you have to use `AJAX`, `socket.io` or `WebSockets`. 
If you only have to update the back-end if the clients wants to you should use `AJAX`. If your client has to be notified by the back-end (Server), you should use `socket.io` or `WebSockets` for that.
Because you are using NodeJs, i would recommend you to use `socket.io`.

Just have a look at it:
https://socket.io/

---

Here a example for your code:

First install the package:

```
npm install -S socket.io

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');

// add socket io
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

// connect to port
app.listen(3030);

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/flood';

// setup server
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // add event
    socket.on('data', function (data) {

        // execute after event was emitted
        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
            var collec_name = data.collec;
            var field_name = data.field;
            var value = data.value

            db.collection(collec_name).find({ data0: value }, { [field_name]: 1, _id: 0 }).toArray(function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                // TODO add emmit
                console.log(result);
                db.close();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script src="path/to/socket.io"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost');

        // send message
        socket.emit('data', { 
            collec: "99",
            field: "datal",
            value: 311
        });

        // TODO add listener
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0.000115;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with that. It would be helpful for me to understand if you please modify my above scripts or give a solution script based on my above scripts.

Comment: It's not working. At first, I run the HTML script and then executed server side node.js script with node hello.js but obtained nothing. Also, showing handler error if I don't remove handler in the server script. Could you please give me the complete client side and server side scripts? Also, I am not sure what I need to include in the TODO part of your script. I just want to run HTML page so that it can automatically send parameters to the server side script and then get the result back automatically to display. Is it possible with your scripts? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem. As I didn't find any perfect solution on net, I thought it will be helpful for other users (who are facing similar problem) if I post a general solution to a similar problem here. Please excuse if this is not the right place to post the solution.

**My Solution:** This is not the exact solution of my above example but I think it is better to provide a general solution to a similar problem so that anyone can always modify/update this solution according to his/her example/need as basic approach will be always same. At first, you need to have http, express and body-parser and you can do by following the commands:

```
npm install http
npm install express
npm install body-parser --save
```

**A general problem**: Suppose, I have two numbers (for instance `a = 20` and `b = 24` in the client HTML page and I want to sum up the numbers from the server side and get the summation result (`sum = 44`) back in the client side to display in the HTML page. Then use the following nodejs and ejs scripts-

**index.ejs:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example solution</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){               
               $('#loadRequest').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log('Load_button clicked');
                    var data = {};
                    data.a = 20; //input
                    data.b = 24; //input

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data), //input data to be sent to the server
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        url: 'http://localhost:80/endpoint',                        
                        success: function(res) {
                            console.log('success');
                            console.log(res);
                            $("#demo").html(res);  //summation displayed in the HTML page   
                        }
                    });

                });             
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id ="demo"></p>
        <button id="loadRequest">Load</button>   
    </body>
</html>
```

**server.js**:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  //tell Express we're using EJS
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');  //set path to *.ejs files
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //render index.ejs file
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/endpoint', function(req, res){
    var x = req.body.a; //received input 1 from client side
    var y = req.body.b; //received input 2 from client side
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    var sum =x+y;
    console.log(sum);
    res.send(String(sum)); //sending summation to the client
});

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

It worked perfectly. Please let me know if you have any comment/feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You can either implement an API yourself using AJAX, WebSockets or socket.io - or you can go ahead and take a look into [Express](https://expressjs.com/) framework.

Setting up a Node.js server using Express will not only provide you access to a rich API interface, it would also make your task much easier.

Using it, you can set up a simple route like this:

```
app.post('/compute', function(req, res){
  // compute 'result'
  res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: I am new and I never used express before. Can you please help by updating my above scripts? Thank you.